# read localhost e-mail with thunderbird

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, email-client, postfix

What would be simplest IMAP server allow Thunderbird to read messages to user@localhost for Ubuntu Linux?

My **assumption** was that if [mailutils](http://mailutils.org/) could read mail with the "mail" command then IMAP or POP was configured, which was incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open the Account Settings menu you should be able to add an new account using Movemail.   It should be located in Account Actions under Add Other Accounts.   This should then move mail from the spool folder into your inbox.

Personally, I use `Dovecot` with `Maildir` format directories populated by `proccmail`.   This allows me to read mail both locally and remotely using the same mailstore.   I also provide webmail access using `Squirrelmail`.

Comment: Right you are!  It was in file -> New -> Other Accounts for me (Linux).

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest installing [alpine/pine](http://www.washington.edu/alpine/) (available in most repositories) if you're looking for a lightweight mail reader that can address locally-delivered mail. Short of that, Thunderbird will need to interface with a POP3 or IMAP server on the host.

Comment: in this case I'm specifically looking for a GUI and am used to Thunderbird.  I'll look into an IMAP server.

Answer (score 4):

My first suggestion would have been to set up a simple POP or IMAP server, but [this email](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=40236) suggests that Thunderbird has native support for local mail accounts via the *movemail* account type.  I have never tried this out, and in your position I would probably just set up something like [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/) (which is a POP/IMAP server).

Actually, to be honest, in your position I would simply use [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/), but that's not necessarily the best choice for all people.

**EDIT**: Additional discussion about Thunderbird and movemail is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1718795).

Comment: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/mailnews/movemail/index.html looks defunct, too bad.  doesn't seem such an thing to want.